# How to get Date String Format in JavaScript using moment or vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

So I have this sample date `"2015-11-13T18:43:58.720Z"` and I want to get the string format of it. I used `moment` to get the string format.

```
const d = '2015-11-13T18:43:58.720Z';
const format = moment(d).creationData().format;
// output is YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSSZ
```

But when I do something like

```
const a = moment(d).format('MM-DD-YYYY HH:mmA');
// output is 11-14-2015 02:43AM

const b = moment('11-14-2015 02:43AM', 'MM-DD-YYYY HH:mmA').format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSSZ');
// output is different 2015-11-14T02:43:00.0000+08:00
// expecting 2015-11-13T18:43:58.720Z
```

How can I get the proper string format of `(2015-11-13T18:43:58.720Z)` using moment or vanilla js when getting current timestamp?

Comment: Hmm.. which output do you want to get? this one '11-14-2015 02:43AM'?

Comment: @wentjun updated my post thanks

Comment: got it! And your input is..? The current time?

Comment: @wentjun yes, let's say moment().format('What's the correct format?');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in Vanilla JavaScript, without moment.js.

```
const newDate = new Date().toISOString();
console.log(newDate)
```

This converts the input into the date in [ISO](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) format (as a string).

More examples:

```js
    const newDate = new Date().toISOString();
    const anotherDate = new Date('2015-11-13T18:43:58.720Z').toISOString();
    const yetAnotherDate = new Date(2019, 3, 15, 10).toISOString();
    console.log(newDate);
    console.log(anotherDate);
    console.log(yetAnotherDate);
```